# How to find the image ID participating in the mosaicing in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, image-processing, google-earth-engine

I want to find the image ID participating in the mosaicing, here is my mosaic process. Just the partial images appearing in the mosaicing result, not all those meet the filter conditions. The color difference of the whole image is too big, I want to match each image with histogram and then mosaic it, or maybe you have a better way?

```
var myimage = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
              .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-08-01').sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 
false).mosaic();                
var myimage1 = myimage.clip(dongbei);
var Viscolor= {
bands              :['B8','B4','B3'],
min                : 0.0,
max                : 10000.0,
};

Map.addLayer(myimage1, Viscolor, ' Color (843)');
```

"dongbei" is the shapefile I uploaded.

[image: image after mosaicing]

Comment: What do you want to do with the IDs when you have them? Just display them, or something more? This will affect what the best way to proceed is.

Comment: Histogram matching all images with standard image, and then extract crops.Thank you.

Comment: Matching can be done with ID.